# How do you script an addEventListener to toggle back a hamburger menu in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

Alright so I'm at the last phase of adding finishing touches to my website in order to publish it over the internet but I can't quite figure out how to add an eventListener that closes the navbar hamburger menu without having to manually scroll back up to the landing page to toggle it back. This is what I have so far.

```
//Select element function
const selectElement = function (element) {
    return document.querySelector(element);
};

let menuToggler = selectElement('.menu-toggle');
let body = selectElement('body');

menuToggler.addEventListener('click', function () {
    body.classList.toggle('open');
});

// Parallax scrolling effect
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    const parallax = document.querySelector('.parallax');
    let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
  
    parallax.style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrollPosition * -.10 + 'px)';
  });
```

Here's a ss of the HTML document with the nav tag for context; I'd appreciate a thorough explanation of what the js bit is doing as I'm fairly new to it. : ) Cheers!
[image: Nav tag section]

[Attached is a link to a video demonstrating how the hamburger menu responds](https://youtu.be/6YtsWAef3J8)

Answer (score 1):

You want to add an event listener on the entire `document`, and check if the clicked element is your menu button, your nav element, or a child of your nav element. If it is not then remove the class.

```
document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    //the element clicked
    let target = e.target;

    //your nav element
    let nav = document.querySelector('nav');

    //if it's not the menu button, or nav, or a child of nav
    if(target != menuToggler && target != nav && target.closest('nav') != nav){
        body.classList.remove('open');
    }
});
```

You could also use a key event like the user hitting `ESC`, in which you would just remove the class

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
    if(e.key=="Escape"){
        body.classList.remove('open');
    }
});
```

If you need to close it after a link in your nav has been clicked then add the remove code to your existing link listeners or add a new one to your links (or a delegated listener on your nav) and remove it there

```
document.querySelector('nav').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
   if(e.target.classList.contains('nav-link')){
       body.classList.remove('open');
   }
});
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly! Thank you for going in depth with your comments and explaining what each line does :)

Answer (score 1):

To close navbar when click a nav-link you can do this:

```
const menuToggler = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
const body = document.body;
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");

Array.from(navItems).map(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
      body.classList.remove('open');
  });
});

menuToggler.addEventListener('click', function () {
    body.classList.toggle('open');
});

// Parallax scrolling effect
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    const parallax = document.querySelector('.parallax');
    let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
  
    parallax.style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrollPosition * -.10 + 'px)';
  });
```